# Evaluating an integral using a gamma function

Tags: integration

I evaluated $\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x(y+1)}dx$.

I did it by parts I got $e^{-x}$, but if I apply the gamma functions I get different results.

Comment: Is $\int^\infty_0 x e^{-x(y+1)} \, \mathrm{d} x$ the integral you are trying to evaluate?

Comment: @Dmoreno, yes that's the integral, sorry I went offline due to network problems

Comment: Then, I hope you find my answer clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to evaluate:

$$J = \int^\infty_0 x e^{-x(y+1)} \, \mathrm{d} x,$$ let $v = x \, (y+1)$, and assume $y+1 > 0$. Therefore:

$$J = \int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{(y+1)^2} v e^{-v} \, \mathrm{d} v.$$ Recall now the definition of the [Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html), for which we have $z = 2$. Thus:

$$J = \frac{1}{(y+1)^2} \Gamma(2), $$ but $\Gamma(2) = 1! = 1$.

Hope you find this useful. Cheers!

Comment: Why are the solutions different

Comment: Different from what?

Comment: I tried integration by parts and it leads to the same result